# Parse AndroidManifest with only NDK without use the java layer

Tags: android, c, linux, android-ndk, android-manifest

is there a way to parse the AndroidManifest with only NDK without use the java layer?

greets

Comment: Probably not via an API. But maybe look at this: http://www.olafdietsche.de/2015/05/11/exploring-android-binary-xml-file-format

Comment: What would be the result of this "parsing"? Anything that isn't available in [`PackageInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html)?